# ClassNotFoundException in Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: weblogic

Well, I have a problem With My Web Application. It's Deployed in Weblogic 10.3.6. The estructure of my application is:

Ear

```
   - APP-INF
           Lib 
               Common Libraries
   META-INF
   .War File
        WEB-INF
              - lib
                    BankAccountStatement_wsdl.jar
              - classes
              - weblogic.xml
              - web.xml
```

The problem is that the war search all of the jars just into the ear's libraries (app-inf/lib) and I need, the war search the jar in it own package (Web-inf/lib) and then in the Ear's package.

This is the estructure of the war's jar:

com.grupoaval.accounts.v1.classes

I put this line in the war file named weblogic.xml but it doesn't work.

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.spi.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.grupoaval.accounts.v1.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Thanks for your responses!!

Answer (score 0):

use the flag, prefer-web-inf-classes

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP571